# Difference in memcpy and strncpy for struct copying

Tags: c, struct, memcpy, strncpy

I have the below code. I am trying to copy a struct to a string. I want to understand why the output varies between strncpy and memcpy.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
struct a{
    int len;
    int type;
};
int main(){
    struct a aa={98,88};
    char str[10]="";
    char str2[10]="";

    strncpy(str,&aa,sizeof(struct a));
    memcpy(str2,&aa,sizeof(struct a));
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)printf("%2d",str[i]);
    printf("\n");
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)printf("%2d",str2[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Below is the Output:

```
98 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
98 0 0 088 0 0 0 0 0
```

I understand the strncpy will copy till it hits '\0' (or the size limit), but i don't have '\0' value in the struct. Can someone please help me understand this.
Purpose of doing this: trying to send a struct over network. Though I am planning to implement serialization, I wanted to understand the behavior

EDIT:
1)Suggested by Keith Thompson

Below is the warning generated.

```
incompatible pointer types passing 'struct a *' to parameter of type 'const char *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
```

2)I modified the code a bit to use int array:

(Putting this for reference. I understand that in this case, memcpy copies the variable of struct in the first two elements of the array as the size is sufficient for the struct variable.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
struct a{
    int len;
    int type;
};
int main(){
    struct a aa={98,88};
    int str[10]={0};
    int str2[10]={0};

    strncpy(str,&aa,sizeof(struct a));
    memcpy(str2,&aa,sizeof(struct a));
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)printf("%2d",str[i]);
    printf("\n");
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)printf("%2d",str2[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Below is the o\p:

```
98 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
9888 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Below are the warnings generated:

```
incompatible pointer types passing 'int [10]' to parameter of type 'char *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
incompatible pointer types passing 'struct a *' to parameter of type 'const char *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
```

Comment: Your structure is not a string. `strncpy` operates on strings. That call shouldn't even compile; you should at least get a warning passing a `struct a*` argument to `strncpy`, which expects a `char*`. Even for strings, `strncpy` should usually be avoided; [see my rant on the topic here](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html).

Comment: It did thrown a warning.

Comment: Please update your question to show the exact warning; that's very important information.

Comment: Thanks @KeithThompson Added the warning. Added one other example too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but I don't have '\0' value in the struct.

Actually, you do have at least six `'\0'`-s there: assuming that `int` is 32-bit, the upper three bytes of both `98` and `88` are all zeros. They would make `strncpy` stop copying. The function is designed for fixed-length strings, so one should not use it with arbitrary `struct`s. `memcpy`, on the other hand, will copy everything.

> Purpose of doing this: trying to send a struct over network.

If you would like to send your `struct` over the network, and you would like the packet to be portable, convert both `int`s to network order on the sender side, and back to hardware order on the receiving side. For 32-bit numbers use [`htonl` and `ntohl` functions](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/htonsman.html).

Comment: Thanks, missed that '\0' equal 0.strcpy will stop at 0.

Answer (score 1):

memcpy copies bytes, strcpy copies nul-terminated strings (nul is the 0 byte, 0x00, '\x00')

memcpy always copies the specified number of bytes.  strcpy stops copying when it finds a nul

Answer (score 1):

> but i don't have '\0' value in the struct.

Yes, you do.  Your integer values have 0 bits, which can be interpreted as a `'\0'` when the byte data is interpreted as characters.  Since `strncpy` works "character by character until a terminator is reached", this causes it to stop early.

`memcpy` copies the specified number of bytes, *always*, which makes it work.  It is more appropriate in this case.

Comment: Thanks, missed that '\0' equal 0